# ActionController::UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view where I will create series and I have a list , from the list I link to the aggregation of my series, but mark this error.

"ActionController::UrlGenerationError"

file index.html.erb

```
<section class="capturar">


</section>

<section class="detalles">

</section>


<center>
<h2 style="color:blue;font-size:32px"> Lista de Series </h2>
<%= link_to "Agregar nueva Serie", new_series_path,:class=>"nuevo" %>


</center>
```

file _formulario_guardar.html.erb

```
<section class="formulario">

<%= form_for @serie do |f| %> 


<form>


 <%= f.label "Titulo" %>
      <%= f.text_field :class=>"caja"%>



   <p>
      <%= f.submit "Enviar",:class=>"button success" %> <%= link_to "Cancelar", series_path,:class=>"button alert" %>
   </p>

   </form>

<% end %>
</section>

<br><br>
```

Function new

```
 def new
           @serie = Serie.new();

  end
```

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: the line of error is in the number 3 of _formulario_guardar.html.erb

Comment: Can you add the pertinent lines from your `config/routes.rb`